# Attached images in Folder or Database?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm currently working on a .NET (core 3.1) website project and I am a little stuck on how to handle images and as I could not find a proper response for my case, here it is.
I'm working on a reports system where the user should be allowed to create a report and attach images if necessary. My question is, should I store the images in a database or a folder? The images will not contain "National security threats" but I guess they could be of a private nature.
Is it a good practice to store them on a Database?
I found it a bit messy the procedure to store them:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IFormFile image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            byte[] p1 = null; //As I understand, it should be store as byte[]
            using (var fs1 = image.OpenReadStream())
            using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                fs1.CopyTo(ms1);
                p1 = ms1.ToArray();
            }
            Image img = new Image(); //This is my Image model
            img.Img = p1; //The property .IMG is of type "varbinary" on the DB.

            _imagesDB.Images.Add(img); //My context
            await _imagesDB.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index)); //if everything went well go back to index-
        }
        return View(report);
    }
```

This is more or less ok (I guess) but I was not able to read it back from the database and send it to the View for showing.

Any ideas on how to read back the images from my context and, specially, how to send it from the controller to the View?

Thanks in advance.-
Alvaro.

Comment: Looks OK, except that if you are doing this a lot then I would consider doing raw SQL and streaming the data straight through. Even moderately sized images are going to chew up your Large Object Heap. If they are very large you could consider just storing a filename (perhaps use `FILESTREAM` on SQL Server)

Comment: Read the article [To BLOB or Not To BLOB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem/) (click View Publication to download).

Comment: What database do you use? In Sql Server, there is [FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pros and cons of both methods of storing files. It's *convenient* to have your files where your data is - however it takes a toll on the database side.

- Text (the file path) in the database is only a few thousand bytes *max* (`varchar` data type, not the `text` data type in SQL), while a file can be enormous.
- Imagine you wanted to query 1,000,000 users (*hypothetically*) - you would also be querying 1,000,000 files. That an enormous amount of data. Storing text (*the file path*) is minimal and a query could retrieve 1,000,000 rows of text rather quickly.
- This can slow down your web app by causing longer load times due to your queries. I've had this issue personally and had to actually make a lazy load workaround to speed up the app.
- Also, you have to consider the backup/restore process for your database. The larger the database then the longer your backup/restore times will take - and databases only grow. I heard a story about a company who backed up their database nightly, but their backup time took longer than a day due to files in their database. They weren't even done with the backup the day prior when the next backup started.

There are other factors to consider but those few alone are significant considerations.

---

In regards to the C# view/controller process...

Files are stored as bytes in a database (`varbinary`). You'll have to query the data and store them in a `byte[]` just like you are now and convert it to a file.

Here's a simplified snippet of one of my controllers in my .NET Core 3.1 web app.

- This was only to **download** 1 PDF file - you will have to change it for your needs of course.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string docId, string docSource)
{
    //  Some kinda of validation...
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(docId))
    {
        //  These are my query parameters (I'm using Dapper)
        var p = new 
        { 
            docId,
            docSource  // This is just a parameter for my specific query
        };

        //  Query the database for the document
        //  DocumentModel doc = some kinda of async query using 
        //      the p variables as parameters
        //  I cut this part out since your database methods may be different
      
        try
        {
            //  Return the file
            return File(doc.Content, "application/pdf", doc.LeafName);
        }
        catch
        {
            // You'll probably want to pass some kind of error message to your view
            return View();
        }

    }

    return View();
}
```

The `doc.Content` are the bytes and the `doc.LeafName` is just the name of the document.

You can also pass the file back to your View by setting properties on it's ViewModel/Model.

```cs
return View(new YourViewModel
{
     SomeViewModelProperty = someProp,
     Documents = documents
});
```

If you use a file server that's accessible to your API or web app then I believe you can retrieve the file directly from there.

Comment: Point #1 is not true, `varchar(max)` can be 2GB although shouldn't store images in `varchar` anyway. #2 only happens in the case of poor indexing, #3 only happens if you use `select *` Only point #4 is true

Comment: @Charlieface In regards to #1, I only meant to just compare how storing text uses less storage than storing an entire file - but you're right, it can exceed a few *thousand* bytes. In regards to #2, and **especially** #3, these are still true... I had an issue where I only needed ~30 PDFs per order from a database that was indexed properly and noticed a substantial difference when including/excluding the files from the query. The only fields in that table were (1) the DocumentID which was indexed, and (2) the file as `varbinary`.

Comment: #1 Not sure your point, you can store an entire large file of text also (JSON and base64 binary being the worst examples of this). #2 and #3 Obviously if you `select` the data then that is what will happen, which is what I said. Indexing helps if you want *other* columns and *not* the data. You haven't made any clear difference in how it would compare performance-wise to reading off the file system? Pretty similar as the mechanics are almost the same.

Comment: @Charlieface #1 I meant storing the file path vs the file itself. I'll update my answer to specifically state that. I assumed you meant that speed is the same when including/excluding the files in your initial comment - which is why I mentioned the differences, because why wouldn't he include the files in the query if he wanted to get the files from the query. The performance difference is noticed when the app is waiting on the query to finish. The app would get the file information directly via file path returned from the query rather than waiting on the query.

Comment: But the file path itself doesn't get you the file data either, you still need to "wait" on opening the file and loading it from disk. You have the same wait time either way if it is a large file. But best is to do it asynchronously anyway.

Comment: Hej Brxndxn (and everyone)!
Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I really appreciate it!!!
I have everything much more clear now, only one thing remains. When I post a normal static picture with a <img> tag, I can easily include the path of the image, but which path should I use with an image coming from a ViewModel? what should I write in src="" ??

Thanks again!!!
Alvaro.-

Comment: @Charlieface yes but it would be handled by the app and gives you other possibilities, like lazy loading when the user scrolls down the page like Instagram, or when the user changes pages. Imagine being a front end developer and you want to handle how the loading is displayed on a per-item basis. You can display the progress of each item loading asynchronously in the app if the app handles it. Also - it would take a load off of your database server when you think of scaling. Imagine a million users making those kind of requests that returns that much data.

Comment: You can lazy-load from the DB as well, in fact I wrote code to do exactly that with images recently. "Imagine a million users making those kind of requests that return that much data" from a file server, it's the same thing.

Comment: @Charlieface but a file server is separate. Why tax your database server and potentially slow down performance when you don't have to. But you're right about lazy loading from a database, it is possible. I suppose we just have different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: Don't worry I know. You're right in the essentials: large files I wouldn't do this with, but only because of the backup issue. I'm a dba and sysadmin (as well as a developer), so I worry about both sides of the coin.

Comment: @LucaProdan  If you wanted to display your image via controller then your HTML would probable resemble something similar to `<img src="@Url.Action("Download", new { docId = 1, docSource = "source" })"/>`. `"Download"` is your controller's method name that returns a **file** and the second parameter is a object for your method's parameters. This will call your controller's action to get the file. However, if you wanted to display your image via ViewModel filepath then your HTML may look like  `<img src="@Url.ImagePath(Model.ImageFilePath)"/>` where `ImageFilePath` is the path of your image